# Trying to run a shell script with couple of simple dmidecode commands, when executing script it adds '?' at the end of each file

Tags: linux, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'HELLO'

dmidecode -t system > sys.txt
```

When I do ls, it shows sys.txt? file instead of sys.txt. I am totally new to linux scripting please help

Comment: To find out why, use strace. To find out what it is, use hexdump

Answer (score 2):

You have some non-printable character in script after **sys.txt**. Most probably it's the **\r** if you created this file on Windows. In this case - try to convert it with  **dos2unix**.

If you have caught some another non-printable char - some called these gremlins - try convert with **tr**.

```
tr -d '[\000-\010\014\016-\037\177]' < dirty.sh > clean.sh
```

Comment: \r on linux typically appears either as ^M or by erasing the current line, not as '?'